# Forms and Dialog.Result.None

Tags: c#, winforms

I am learning about Forms and somehow can't figure out what's the problem with this code that when I want to press either button with Dialog.Result.Yes or button with Dialog.Result.No in Form2 to keep the Form2 open it anyway closes after clicking on one of them.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Formular2 Form2 = new Formular2();
        Form2.ShowDialog();
        if (Form2.DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
        }
        else if (Form2.DialogResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
        }
    }

}
```

Thanks for any advice

Comment: by the time you get to your If statements your form is already closing. You need to use Form2's FormClosing event to stop the Form from closing.

Comment: My answer code lets you achieve what you want; but I'm still confused about what you wish to achieve by doing this? Like, if you are not using the `DialogResult` property of Form2, why doing if...else, just set it to `.None`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the Form2 open, you need to set the DialogResult property of Form2, not the DialogResult property of Form1.

You need to move this logic in the button on Form2 that close the Form2

So, suppose to have a button on Formular form class named buttonOK and its property DialogResult is set to DialogResult.OK.
Then in that class code you write the event handler for the button click event (not the MouseClick event)

```
private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // Perform some logic to validate the inputs and if something is wrong return false
    if(SomeLogicToAcceptTheForm() == false)
    {
        // Inform the user of the error
        MessageBox.Show("Your input is not valid");
        // Stop the closing process of this Formular instance 
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    }

    // If your logic accepts the input, then the code continue at this point 
    // This will cause the form to exit from the ShowDialog call 
    // and you can read the current form DialogResult value.

}
```

**EDIT**
To better understand this flow you should consider that, BEFORE calling the event handler for the button click event, the forms engine sets the Form's DialogResult property from the value present in the button's DialogResult property. So, if your validation turns out to be correct you don't need to do anything and the form closes returning DialogResult.OK (or whatever you have put in the Button's DialogResult property).

Answer (score 0):

In the `Form2` pick control for assigning respective dialog result.
Same `DialogResult` will be produced by the Form2 control if you click on it.

Example in **Form2**:

```
button1.DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
button2.DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
```

Now pressing any of these buttons should close the `Form2`.

If you want to restrict closing on `button1` and `button2`. Following changes in the Click event are required:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
}
```

**Form1**:

In result you could see what is result, by looking into `Form2.DialogResult`. You can do this as you get results from `Form2` dialog:

```
Formular2 Form2 = new Formular2();
Form2.ShowDialog();

if (Form2.DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    //
}
else if (Form2.DialogResult == DialogResult.No)
{
   //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **act** of setting a DialogResult will cause the Form to close returning that result to the Form that created the instance, that way it can check the result and take the appropriate action. In your case since you want to keep the second form open you either need to not assign the DialogResult.No to the button and do like Steve suggests or you can intercept the Form's FormClosing event, test for the DialogResult if DialogResult.No set to None and cancel the Closing of the Form.
*Though I would suggest not using a DialogResult if you are wanting to keep the Form Open.*

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
}

private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.DialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On any windows form displayed as modal (using `ShowDialog()`), the act of setting DialogResult will cause to hide the modal form and return control to calling code. [Read Remarks from this page of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

If you wish to show your form again, you can do the following:

```
private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Formular2 Form2 = new Formular2();
    Form2.ShowDialog();
    if (Form2.DialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Form2.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    }
    else if (Form2.DialogResult == DialogResult.No)
    {
        Form2.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
    }

    Form2.Show(); // or Form2.ShowDialog()
}
```